# Swift: Can't Add Button to Navigation Bar of ABPersonViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, abaddressbook

I've noticed that if I have a `UIViewController` in a `UINavigationController`, something like:

```
let vc = UIViewController()
let nav = UINavigationController()
nav.viewControllers = [vc]
self.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Adding a button the navigation bar is as easy as: `vc.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = ...`

If however, the view controller is of type `ABPersonViewController`, like this:

```
let person = ABPersonViewController()
person.personViewDelegate = self
person.displayedPerson = info
let nav = UINavigationController()
nav.viewControllers = [person]
self.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I can't add a button the navigation bar in the same way; `person.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = ...`, as seems to be done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414561/how-to-add-a-return-button-for-abpersonviewcontrollers-navigationbar), does nothing.

Is there, then, a way to add a button to the navigation bar of an `ABPersonViewController`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a button on ABPersonViewController. Even if you are able to add, it will be rejected by apple. What you can do is make a custom view like ABPersonViewController and change whatever you want in it. (My personal opinion is that ABPersonViewController is fine and you should not have a problem living with it).

Comment: I'm hesitant to make a custom view, seeing as since `ABPersonViewController` can't be subclassed, I would have to write it in its entirety—I'd rather find a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to just create a View Controller file for your `ABPersonViewController` and set the button normally in `viewDidLoad`.

ie:

`self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton`

You could add the button to the bar non-programatically by adding a Navigation Item to the view and then adding a bar button item.

Comment: I can't create a file for it because I can't have my VC class inherit from it—I would just have to create an instance of it and present it anyway.